# Why when I use print(type()) in cgi, it returns nothing in my webages?

Tags: python-3.x, cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print('content-type: text/html\n')

print(type(True))
```

When I excute this code in teminal, it returned

`<class 'bool'>`

But when I excute this code in cgi, it returned nothing..

Comment: How are you redirecting your "output"? Perhaps try `print(type(True), file=sys.stdout)`